# jQuery is not serializing form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have one question, I have this form and when I make a serialize in jQuery script it returns nothing.

Can you help me please?

This is my form:

```
<form id="tabb2">
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Estudios</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_estudios" name="p_estudios">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_estudios" name="d_estudios" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Funciones del puesto</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_func_puesto" name="p_func_puesto">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_func_puesto" name="d_func_puesto" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Experiencia</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_experiencia" name="p_experiencia">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_experiencia" name="d_experiencia" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Trayectoria Laboral</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_tray_laboral" name="p_tray_laboral">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_tray_laboral" name="d_tray_laboral" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Comportamiento y Arreglo Fisico Durante la Entrevista</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_comp_arr_fisico" name="p_comp_arr_fisico">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_comp_arr_fisico" name="d_comp_arr_fisico" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Evaluacion Final</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_eval_final" name="p_eval_final">
                <option value="No Recomendable">No Recomendable</option>
                <option value="Recomendable">Recomendable</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_eval_final" name="d_eval_final" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->

        <hr id="line">
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="save2"><a href="javascript:;">Guardar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

And this is my ajax code:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
            $('.save2').on('click', function(){

                var dataString = $('#tabb2').serialize();
                alert(dataString);

            });

        });
```

Comment: Don't know if it will solve but you'd better bind the click event on the a anchor instead of the li. Also it will be better to use `$( "#tabb2" ).submit` instead. If you validate your form by typing enter, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Please check the below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('.save2').on('click', function(){

                var dataString = $('#tabb2').serialize();
                alert(dataString);

            });

        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="tabb2">
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Estudios</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_estudios" name="p_estudios">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_estudios" name="d_estudios" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Funciones del puesto</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_func_puesto" name="p_func_puesto">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_func_puesto" name="d_func_puesto" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Experiencia</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_experiencia" name="p_experiencia">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_experiencia" name="d_experiencia" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Trayectoria Laboral</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_tray_laboral" name="p_tray_laboral">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_tray_laboral" name="d_tray_laboral" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Comportamiento y Arreglo Fisico Durante la Entrevista</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_comp_arr_fisico" name="p_comp_arr_fisico">
                <option value="0">Cero</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_comp_arr_fisico" name="d_comp_arr_fisico" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <label>Evaluacion Final</label><br />
        <pre>
            <label>Punteo</label><br />
            <select id="p_eval_final" name="p_eval_final">
                <option value="No Recomendable">No Recomendable</option>
                <option value="Recomendable">Recomendable</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Descripcion</label><br />
            <textarea id="d_eval_final" name="d_eval_final" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br />
        </pre><br />
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->

        <hr id="line">
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="save2"><a href="javascript:;">Guardar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly but I don't know what else can I do because isn't working in any way.. I have changed the id value a the 'li save2' with a button or input and isn't working I don't know what is the problem. Please help

Comment: If you changed to button use the id of that input like `$('#id').on('click',....)`